# How to get the name of a dynamically created button using and OnClick event in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, button, onclick, dynamically-generated

I need assistance for trying to get the name of a dynamically created button using and OnClick event in Delphi.

I am then want to use the name of that button and store it in a global variable.

This is where I am currently:

```
procedure TMap.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
btnCache : TButton;
begin
 btnCache := TButton.Create(imgAerial);
 with btnCache do
 begin
  onclick := ClickButton;
 end;

procedure TMap.ClickButton(Sender: TObject);
begin
//Code for getting the name of the button
end;
```

Comment: Do you intend to reference the control by this name? Because that won't be possible. You should refer to it by its variable. The name only means anything if you drop it into the form through the IDE (auto-create). Not only don't you assign a name, but even if you do, that name is only a string. As David mentions in his answer, don't expect that name to mean much. If you want to access this button from elsewhere, declare your variable `btnCache` in the form, not in this private procedure.

Comment: Why would you need the name at all? You know that when `ClickButton` is called, `Sender` is the button that was clicked, so just use a local variable of type `TButton`, and assign it the value of `Sender` with a typecast like `MyBtn := (Sender as TButton);`. You can then use `MyBtn` in the code as usual. If your code depends on the string name of the button, you've designed your code wrong.

Answer (score 4):

The button's name can be retrieved by casting `Sender` to the type that introduces `Name`. That is `TComponent`.

```
(Sender as TComponent).Name
```

Don't expect this name to be very informative since your code does not assign a name to the button. As the code is written in the question, the dynamically created button has no name.